# Advertising Studio Integration with Facebook

Tags: marketing-cloud, facebook, social-studio

I'm trying to understand how the integration of Advertising Studio works with Facebook. 
Does anyone have any idea of what kind of information can we retrieve from Facebook Account integrated with Advertising Studio?

Answer (score 3):

Advertising Studio is basically just an easier method for taking your data that sits in SFMC, and securely making it available for ad audiences on social platforms, in your case that being Facebook.

The most common approach would be to create a data extension that contains your segmented audience, map it to a new audience in Advertising Studio, and then through the integration once you activate it that audience becomes targeted on Facebook.

Once you have an audience created you can then create a lookalike audience to target similar contacts that don't already exist in your database (Facebook only feature).

There are more dynamic ways of creating audiences like through Journey Builder, but at the end of the day it's just another way of designating a group of contacts to be targeted on those social platforms.